# PyTorch で二つのコードの差は何ですか？どうして片方だけエラーが出るのかわかる人教えてください

Tags: python, gpu, pytorch

この二つのコードの差は何ですか？どうして片方だけエラーが出るのかわかる人教えてください
両方 `torch.Tensor` 型同士の足し算なのに、なぜ片方だけエラーが出るのですか？
わかる人教えてください。

コードA

```
a=torch.tensor([[10]]).to("cuda:0").half()
b=torch.tensor([2]).to("cuda:0").half()
print(type(a),a)
print(type(b),b)
print(a+b)
print("ok")
```

結果A

```
<class 'torch.Tensor'> tensor([[10.]], device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float16)
<class 'torch.Tensor'> tensor([2.], device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float16)
tensor([[12.]], device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float16)
ok
```

コードB

```
targ=(gamma ** multireward_steps)*targetQN.forward(memory.buffer[idx][0],"net_v")
rew=memory.buffer[idx][2].to("cuda:0")
print(type(targ),targ)
print(type(rew),rew)
targets[i]=rew+targ
```

結果B

```
<class 'torch.Tensor'> tensor([[0.0208]], device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float16)
<class 'torch.Tensor'> tensor([0.], device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float16)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-dff82183a33b> in <module>
    420                     trin.pioritized_experience_replay(batch_size, gamma,step=episode,
    421                                                       state_size=state_,action_size=acthon,
--> 422                                                       multireward_steps=multireward_steps)
    423                 trin.Done(episode)
    424                 mainQN.Done()

<ipython-input-1-dff82183a33b> in pioritized_experience_replay(self, batch_size, gamma, step, state_size, action_size, multireward_steps)
    289             print(type(targ),targ)
    290             print(type(rew),rew)
--> 291             targets[i]=rew+targ
    292 
    293             priority = rank_sum(memory_TDerror.buffer[idx], self.alpha)

~\Anaconda3\envs\pyflan\lib\site-packages\torch\tensor.py in __array__(self, dtype)
    492             return self.numpy()
    493         else:
--> 494             return self.numpy().astype(dtype, copy=False)
    495 
    496     # Wrap Numpy array again in a suitable tensor when done, to support e.g.

TypeError: can't convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.
```

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: can't convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.

このエラーメッセージに書いてある通りで、コピーのためにcudaを使っているTensorを一度cpuで扱うように変えないとだめではないでしょうか。

コードAは`a(Tensor) + b(Tensor)` をしているだけですが
コードBは`targets[i] = rew(Tensor) + targ(Tensor)` で`numpy`へのコピーが発生しています。そこが違います。たぶん`targets[i]`の型が`ndarray`とかなんでしょうね。

Answer (score 0):

コードAとコードBの違いは、コードAは2つのTensorを足し算しているだけですが、コードBはndarrayとTensorを足し算しています。そのため、エラーが発生しています。エラーメッセージに書いてある通りで、コピーのためにcudaを使っているTensorを一度cpuで扱うように変えないとだめです。

このエラーを解決するためには、以下のように書き換えます。

```
targets[i] = rew.cpu() + targ.cpu()
```